# Why is Groovy throwing a ClassCastException from a multi-catch block

Tags: java, groovy

I have the following Groovy test code that is being statically compiled using `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5`...

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.junit.Test
import javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException

@CompileStatic
public class GroovySandbox
{

  @Test
  public void multiCatchClassCastException()
  {
    try
    {
      throw new ArithmeticException( "message" );
    }
    catch ( ArithmeticException | BadRequestException e )
    {
      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }

  }

}
```

When I run the test I get a ClassCastException...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ArithmeticException cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException
```

If I run the exact same code from a Java test file, the test works just fine.

If I throw a BadRequestException in the try block, I'm able to call getMessage() just fine without getting the ClassCastException.  The order that the exception types are listed in the multi-catch block seems to matter.

I'm able to work around this by casting the exception to the Exception type using the `as` keyword, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a good one.  Can you show us how you compiled the Groovy code?  Can you show the imports and the rest of the code for Groovy?

Comment: I updated the post with the missing details.  The only thing that was missing from the source code was the imports.  I'm usually running unit tests via IntelliJ's JUnit or Gradle test runner.  The Gradle (2.7) 'build' task produces the same result.

Comment: If I take off the `@CompileStatic` it seems to work fine. Guessing there's an issue with how the catch block gets parsed with `@CompileStatic`. Probably not the answer you're looking for but it's a place to start.

Comment: What JDK version are you using? Because I tried your example (though with two other unrelated exception types) and I can reproduce your problem, but only with jigsaw.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with Oracle Java 1.8.0_45-b14. Should we file a bug with Groovy ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug, and has been fixed in Groovy 3.0 Alpha (I have tested)

I think it may be also fixed in Groovy 2.6 because they use the same Parrot Parser.